# How to override Contextual Action Bar when selecting text in a WebView in Android?

Tags: android, webview, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

I've googled a lot, and find some tutorials and answers here in stackoverflow, but I am facing some difficults to resolve this issue.

I have a Fragment with a WebView, and I want to show my custom Contextual Action Bar when the user selects some text of my web view. I have two main issues here:

- 1 Currently, my custom CAB is showed when the user performs long click in any part of the web view.
- 2 The text is not selected when the user performs long click in some text of my web view.

Some of my current code:

**Custom interface:**

```
public class SelectActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    }
}
```

**Custom WebView**

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    private SelectActionModeCallback actionModeCallback;

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public ActionMode startActionMode(Callback callback) {
        actionModeCallback = new SelectActionModeCallback();
        return super.startActionMode(actionModeCallback); 
    }
```

**In my fragment, I have this:**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    myWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            view.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private SelectActionModeCallback mActionModeCallback = new SelectActionModeCallback() {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.custom, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_sustom:
                customMethod();
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mActionMode = null;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THERE IS A BETTER WAY! See the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22391169/2608235

---

In short, you can't use an `OnLongClickListener` and keep the selection within a `WebView`. Android does some weird stuff behind the scenes for selecting text within `WebViews`. If you override `OnLongClickListener` in order to call `startActionMode`, you will lose the selection, as you have found out.

What you should do instead is override `startActionMode` in your fragment, rather than its parent `View` (in your case, `CustomWebView`).

I don't have the mod permission to mark this question as a duplicate, but it is.
See my question for more info: [Use a custom contextual action bar for WebView text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/override-onlongtouch-in-a-webview-but-keep-text-selection)