# Selection Handles Not Appearing in WebView (Android 4.0-4.3)

Tags: android, webview, selection, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

I have created a custom `ActionMode.Callback` in order to display a custom contextual action bar for text selection in a `WebView`. It works beautifully in Android 4.4, but in 4.1-4.3, the selection handles are not appearing. I can still perform my custom operations on the single word that is highlighted, but the selection cannot be changed due to the missing handles.

In addition, when the `ActionMode` is destroyed, the selection does not clear from the screen. In contrast, if the user taps elsewhere to clear the selection, the `ActionMode` is not destroyed.

I'm not even sure that `clearFocus()` is the method I should be calling to try to remove the selection. I commented that line and the behavior in 4.4 did not change; it still worked flawlessly.

What can be done to fix these issues?

---

This is my current implementation:

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback;

    @Override
    public ActionMode startActionMode(Callback callback) {
        ViewParent parent = getParent();
        if (parent == null) {
            return null;
        }
        mActionModeCallback = new CustomActionModeCallback();
        return parent.startActionModeForChild(this, mActionModeCallback);
    }

    private class CustomActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown.
        // Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // This method is called when the handlebars are moved.
            loadJavascript("javascript:getSelectedTextInfo()");
            return false; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId() {
            case R.id.button_1:
                // do stuff
                break;
            case R.id.button_2:
                // do stuff
                break;

            ... // cases for other buttons

            default:
                break;
            }

            mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
            return true;
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO This does not work in 4.3 (and probably anything older).
            clearFocus(); // Remove the selection highlight and handles.

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out what I was doing incorrectly that was causing this behavior. Fortunately, I did find a solution that displays the handlebars appropriately, and allows for custom actions. That solution can be found at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22391169/2608235

In short, instead of creating your own `ActionMode`, remove the default selection actions (copy, paste, etc) and replace them with your own `menu.xml` layout using `MenuInflater` within an override of `onActionModeStarted`. Define an `onClick` for your menu elements, implement that method in your `Activity`, and you're done.