# How to add context menu for webview, such as text selection, open in web browser, etc...?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-contextmenu

This is a short question.
Suppose I have a WebView showing a website, how do I make it have a context menu of text-selection and long-click-on-links ?

Text-selection has the ability to copy the selected text, for example, and links can have the ability to open them in the web browser or at least be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/use-a-custom-contextual-action-bar-for-webview-text-selection ?

Comment: @Kenneth Where's the part there that tells you which link/selected-text was chosen? I don't see how to get it there. I don't get it.