# Horizontal menu inflater on long click for web view

Tags: android, webview, selection, long-click

I am having a problem with the webview selection on longClick. I already had an implementation of a customized menu that launches on longClick. But the default menu is launching as well. I am trying to customize the default menu, but I'm not knowing how to capture the click of the user on an item.

I have tried the following, but the menu is becoming vertical and hiding the selection, so I cannot select more words or change the selection.

```
  @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);


    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    /*
        public void inflate (int menuRes, Menu menu)
            Inflate a menu hierarchy from the specified XML resource. Throws InflateException if there is an error.

        Parameters
            menuRes : Resource ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g., R.menu.main_activity)
            menu : The Menu to inflate into. The items and submenus will be added to this Menu.

    */
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    // Handle the menu item selection
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.dict_menu:
            // Render the page again
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"dict_menu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.q_menu:
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"q_menu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.hi_menu:
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"hi_menu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    return false;
}
```

With menu xml as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
     <item android:id="@+id/dict_menu"
    android:title="قاموس" />
     <item android:id="@+id/q_menu"
    android:title="اقتباس" />
     <item android:id="@+id/hi_menu"
    android:title="تظليل" />
</menu>
```

Therefore instead of having this result: (I get this result when I don't implement the following methods: onCreateContextMenu, onContextItemSelected which enable me to capture when an item of the menu is chosen)

[image]

I get the following:

[image]

The first screenshot is received when I use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    System.out.println("onActionModeStarted");
    if (mActionMode == null)
    {
        mActionMode = mode;
        //mode.setTitle("Dictionary");
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
        menu.clear();
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);//mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(myMenu, menu);
    }
    //System.out.println("onActionModeStarted");
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}

public void onContextualMenuItemClicked(MenuItem item) {
    System.out.println("onContextualMenuItemClicked");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.dict_menu:
            // do some stuff
            System.out.println("dict_menu");
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"dict_menu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.hi_menu:
            // do some different stuff
            System.out.println("hi_menu");
          Toast.makeText(mContext,"hi_menu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.q_menu:
            // do some different stuff
            System.out.println("q_menu");
           Toast.makeText(mContext,"q_menu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            // ...
            super.onContextItemSelected(item);
            break;
    }

    // This will likely always be true, but check it anyway, just in case
    /*if (mActionMode != null) {
        mActionMode.finish();
    }*/
}

@Override
public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
    mActionMode = null;
    super.onActionModeFinished(mode);
    System.out.println("onActionModeFinished");
}

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!---<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"-->
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <item android:id="@+id/dict_menu"
         android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
         android:title="قاموس" />

     <item android:id="@+id/q_menu"
         android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
         android:title="اقتباس" />

     <item android:id="@+id/hi_menu"
         android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
         android:title="تظليل" />

 </menu>
```

This is causing the following error:

```
  android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick        handler onContextualMenuItemClicked in class android.app.ContextImpl
  08-10 09:01:21.602 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(MenuInflater.java:243)
  08-10 09:01:21.602 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:464)
  08-10 09:01:21.602 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:498)
  08-10 09:01:21.602 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:191)
  08-10 09:01:21.602 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:112)
  08-10 09:01:21.602 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at BookReader.onActionModeStarted(BookReader.java:3346)
  08-10 09:01:21.602 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionMode(DecorView.java:1034)
  08-10 09:01:21.602 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionModeForChild(DecorView.java:982)
  08-10 09:01:21.602 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:828)
  08-10 09:01:21.602 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:828)
  08-10 09:01:21.602 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:828)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:828)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:6398)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at org.chromium.content.browser.SelectionPopupController.showActionModeOrClearOnFailure(SelectionPopupController.java:45)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.onSelectionEvent(ContentViewCore.java:579)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:7)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onContextualMenuItemClicked [interface android.view.MenuItem]
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1981)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1637)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:     at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(MenuInflater.java:241)
  08-10 09:01:21.603 4931-4931/ W/System.err:   ... 22 more
  08-10 09:01:21.604 4931-4931/ A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(243)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In whichever activity is hosting your `WebView`, override `onActionModeStarted()`, manipulate the menu items, and assign listeners to each. An example:

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);

    MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    Menu menu = mode.getMenu();

    menu.clear();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_custom, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.custom_one).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ToastMenuItemListener(this, mode, "One!"));
    menu.findItem(R.id.custom_two).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ToastMenuItemListener(this, mode, "Two!"));
    menu.findItem(R.id.custom_three).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ToastMenuItemListener(this, mode, "Three!"));
}

private static class ToastMenuItemListener implements MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    private final Context context;
    private final ActionMode actionMode;
    private final String text;

    private ToastMenuItemListener(Context context, ActionMode actionMode, String text) {
        this.context = context;
        this.actionMode = actionMode;
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        actionMode.finish();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, in fact I had already solved the problem in a similar way and I was going to post the solution. But still thank you for your efforts.

Comment: This answer previously discussed how to do this for a `TextView` (in addition to what remains above). I migrated that to an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765047/8298909, since closing that question as a dupe of this one didn't seem appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution that worked for me, hope it may be useful for someone.**

The only difference from the previous answer is that I created the menu dynamically, cause the static menu for some reason was not responding to menuItemClicked() function.

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    System.out.println("onActionModeStarted");
    if (mActionMode == null)
    {
        mActionMode = mode;
        //mode.setTitle("Dictionary");
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
        menu.clear();
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        List<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
        // get custom menu item
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            menuItems.add(menu.getItem(i));
        }
        menu.clear();
        // reset menu item order
        int size = menuItems.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            addMenuItem(menu, menuItems.get(i), i, true);
        }

    }

    //System.out.println("onActionModeStarted");
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}


private void addMenuItem(Menu menu, MenuItem item, int order, boolean isClick){
    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(item.getGroupId(),
            item.getItemId(),
            order,
            item.getTitle());
    menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    if (isClick)
        // set custom menu item click
        menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                BookReader.this.menuItemClicked(item);
                return true;
            }
        });
}

public void menuItemClicked(MenuItem item)
{
    System.out.println("menuItemClicked");

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.dict_menu:
            testWV.searchInDict();
            if (mActionMode!=null){
                mActionMode.finish();
            }

            break;
        case R.id.hi_menu:
            testWV.highlightWord();

            break;
        case R.id.q_menu:
            testWV.copyQuote();
            if (mActionMode!=null){
                mActionMode.finish();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```