# How to override web view text selection menu in android

Tags: android, webview, android-menu

The basic android's web text selection menu is as shown in image attached below. It has options like copy, share, select all, web search.

[image]

I want to over ride this menus and want them as my own menu list like "mark colour", "mark as imp" etc. I look around most of the questions available about context menu on stack overflow. The most of the question relate with context menu but not giving result as expected. I want menu like below image

[image]

When I perform selection android monitor shows some view creation form viewRoot like

```
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{648898f V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{a66541c V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
```

How to achieve such implementation?

I also gone through https://github.com/naoak/WebViewMarker but not getting proper result.

**What I have done yet?**

I extend WebView of android and I want to make support for minimum SDK 19. When I perform long press I got long press event but I can't get such menus creation api calls.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563790/5672138

Comment: @AshishJohn I already gone through this answer but its not showing menu as in second image.

Comment: @YvetteColomb actually this question doesn't required any example because its normal android's web view nature.

Comment: Got it. But I already added what I tried like https://github.com/naoak/WebViewMarker and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024203/how-to-override-default-text-selection-of-android-webview-os-4-1/22563790#22563790. All menu override questions shows different menu structures. I will put some extra information.

Comment: Have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/use-a-custom-contextual-action-bar-for-webview-text-selection

Comment: I just did. But I don't need CAB implementation. default menus as shown in first image comes from chromium not from CAB. CAB is shown in android 5 and from 6+ its not.

Comment: @Abhishek does this help?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541253/horizontal-menu-inflater-on-long-click-for-web-view/45701223#45701223

Comment: @BenP. its not supports in android SDK < 5

Comment: @Abhishek I'm not sure what you mean. You say in your question "I want to make support for minimum SDK 19". I've tested the linked solution on API 16, so this seems to fit your requirements.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This solution is not depend on Action mode of Activity and work for all android platform**

> **I tried to give answer but it exceeds the character limits so I am putting some code part**

**Reference Link 1 For Selection On Web View**

> https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection

**Reference Link 2 For Making Web View Marker**

> https://github.com/liufsd/WebViewMarker

**Both above links really plays important role and developed by some awesome developers. First Of All Need Some Research On TextSelectionSupport Class From Reference Link 1. I customised two lines of code in TextSelectionSupport class to get rectangle of selection in Selection Listener here.**

> Clone the Sample Project from here
>   https://github.com/ab-cse-2014/WebViewSelection.git
>
> See The implementation of CustomWebView and Use Of TextSelectionSupport class.
>
> This is my web view class in project

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Rect;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Gravity;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.widget.PopupWindow;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.cse.webviewtextselection.R;
 import com.cse.webviewtextselection.webviewmaker.TextSelectionSupport;

 public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

private Context mContext;

private TextSelectionSupport mTextSelectionSupport;

private PopupWindow mPopupWindow;

private int currentTop;

public CustomWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    initSetUp();
    preparePopupWindow();
}

public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    initSetUp();
    preparePopupWindow();
}

public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mContext = context;
    initSetUp();
    preparePopupWindow();
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    mContext = context;
    initSetUp();
    preparePopupWindow();
}

private void initSetUp() {

    mTextSelectionSupport = TextSelectionSupport.support((AppCompatActivity) mContext, this);
    mTextSelectionSupport.setSelectionListener(new TextSelectionSupport.SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void startSelection() {

        }

        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(String text, Rect rect) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showPopAtLocation(mPopupWindow, rect.left, rect.top);
        }

        @Override
        public void endSelection() {
            if (mPopupWindow != null) {
                mPopupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void preparePopupWindow() {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customPopupView =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_popup_layout, null);
    mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(customPopupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
    mPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);

}

private void showPopAtLocation(PopupWindow mPopupWindow, int x, int y) {

    if (mPopupWindow != null) {

        if (currentTop != 0 || currentTop > ((AppCompatActivity)mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight()) {

                if (y > currentTop) {

                    y -= currentTop;

                }

        }

        Log.d("Current Top : ", String.valueOf(currentTop));
        Log.d("Y : ", String.valueOf(y));

        //mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(((AppCompatActivity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.parentRelativeLayout), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, x, y);
        mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(((AppCompatActivity)mContext).getWindow().getDecorView(), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, x, y);


    }

}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int newLeft, int newTop, int oldLeft, int oldTop) {

    currentTop = newTop;


    super.onScrollChanged(newLeft, newTop, oldLeft, oldTop);
}
 }
```

> Custom Popup Menu XML like androids smart text selection(custom_popup_layout.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myCustomMenuLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="12dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menuOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mark With Color"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menuTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mark As Important"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menuThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show More"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

**Output Screen Shots**

[image: Selection One]

[image: Selection Two]

[image: Selection Three]

Comment: This solution is not working when we use "loadDataWithBaseURL"

Comment: I didn't use "loadDataWithBaseURL" anywhere in the above answer. What you want to achieve?

Comment: I used the above code it is working fine when I use   webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/XXX.html"); I am getting an error in console" Uncaught ReferenceError: android is not defined" when I used webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl(baseUrl, data,mimeType,encoding,historyUrl)

Comment: @YerramNaveen - proved values which is used as argument in webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl(baseUrl, data,mimeType,encoding,historyUrl).

Comment: baseUrl: Internal folder path(Where I have CSS and images), data: HTML content String, mimeType: text/html, encoding: UTF-8, hustoryUrl: null

Comment: Please see the code below customWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", getHTMLData(),
                "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

Comment: private String getHTMLData() {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.append("<html>");
        html.append("<head>");

        html.append("<link rel=stylesheet href='css/sample.css'>");
        html.append("</head>");
        html.append("<body>");
        html.append("<div id ='main'> Loading html data in WebView</div>");
        html.append("</body>");
        html.append("</html>");

        return html.toString();
    }

Comment: I resolved the problem we need to add <script src='jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script src='jpntext.js'></script>
<script src='rangy-core.js'></script>
<script src='rangy-serializer.js'></script>
<script src='android.selection.js'></script>
in html head section. Thank you a lot

Comment: how to remove/clear the webview selected background after selecting the menu option.

Comment: I used mTextSelectionSupport.endSelectionMode(); to clear the webview

Comment: webivew is not refreshing when we user webview.loadUrl("about:blank");

Comment: Reason for webview.loadUrl("about: blank"); not working is I created one more constructor in CustomWebview class.  Your code is working perfectly Thank you a lot @Abhishek

Comment: Any updates on this code? The Menu isn't showing anymore.

Comment: @neowinston I need check and let you know.

Answer (score 10):

You need to overwrite action menus of activity

more info you can read :https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

HOW TO OVERWRITE:

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(android.view.ActionMode mode) {
    mode.getMenu().clear();
    Menu menus = mode.getMenu();
    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.highlight,menus);
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}
```

highlight

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/impclick"
        android:title="Mark As Important"
      />
    <item android:id="@+id/colorclick"
        android:title="Mark with color" />
</menu>
```

Comment: can you please let me know on which android version you need to do this, and other thing Activity or compact-activity

Comment: can you shared the Activity snapped code here because is working fine for me. may your doing something wrong in activity level

Comment: Need to update your answer... Not working with compile SDK 26 and above.

Answer (score 4):

what you need is **action mode**, in activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();

        // you can remove original menu: copy, cut, select all, share ... or not
        menu.clear();

        // here i will get text selection by user
        menu.add(R.string.action_menu_preview_card)
                .setEnabled(true)
                .setVisible(true)
                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                    if (mWebview != null) {
                        mWebview.evaluateJavascript("window.getSelection().toString()", value -> {
                            value = StringUtil.trimToNull(value);
                            if (value != null) {
                                // do something about user select
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    // Post a delayed runnable to avoid a race condition
                    // between evaluateScript() result and mode.finish()
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mode.finish();
                        }
                    }, 200);
                    return true;
                });
        super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
    }
```

i has test it above android 21, this can handle action mode menu click, and mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(...) can't do it.

Comment: Able to show menu, but window.getSelection().toString() is retruning empty string

Comment: It works fine, except that there is a race condition between mode.finish() and evaluateJavascript(). Post a delayed Runnable and call mode.finish() there. I'll try to edit code sample to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

i think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/use-a-custom-contextual-action-bar-for-webview-text-selection) can help you .

For the sake of completeness, here is how I fixed the problem:

I followed the suggestion according to this answer, with a little more tweaking to more closely match the overridden code:

public class MyWebView extends WebView {

```
private ActionMode mActionMode;
private mActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback;

@Override
public ActionMode startActionMode(Callback callback) {
    ViewParent parent = getParent();
    if (parent == null) {
        return null;
    }
    mActionModeCallback = new CustomActionModeCallback();
    return parent.startActionModeForChild(this, mActionModeCallback);
}
```

}

Essentially, this forces your customized CAB to appear instead of the Android CAB. Now you have to modify your callback so that the text highlight will go away along with the CAB:

public class MyWebView extends WebView {
    ...
    private class CustomActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
        ...
        // Everything up to this point is the same as in the question

```
    // Called when the user exits the action mode
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        clearFocus(); // This is the new code to remove the text highlight
         mActionMode = null;
    }
}
```

}

That's all there is to it. Be aware that as long as you are using MyWebView with the overridden startActionMode there is NO WAY to get the native CAB (the copy/paste menu, in the case of a WebView). It may be possible to implement that sort of behavior, but that is not the way this code works.
UPDATE: There is a much easier way to do this! The above solution works well, but here is an alternative, easier way.

This solution provides less control over the ActionMode, but it requires far less code than the above solution.

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

```
private ActionMode mActionMode = null;

@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    if (mActionMode == null) {
        mActionMode = mode;
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
        // Remove the default menu items (select all, copy, paste, search)
        menu.clear();

        // If you want to keep any of the defaults,
        // remove the items you don't want individually:
        // menu.removeItem(android.R.id.[id_of_item_to_remove])

        // Inflate your own menu items
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_custom_menu, menu);
    }

    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}

// This method is what you should set as your item's onClick
// <item android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked" />
public void onContextualMenuItemClicked(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.example_item_1:
            // do some stuff
            break;
        case R.id.example_item_2:
            // do some different stuff
            break;
        default:
            // ...
            break;
    }

    // This will likely always be true, but check it anyway, just in case
    if (mActionMode != null) {
        mActionMode.finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
    mActionMode = null;
    super.onActionModeFinished(mode);
}
```

}

Here is an example Menu to get you started:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/example_item_1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_example_1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
    android:title="@string/example_1">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/example_item_2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_example_2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
    android:title="@string/example_2">
</item>
```

That's it! You're done! Now your custom menu will show up, you don't have to worry about the selection, and you barely have to concern yourself with the ActionMode lifecycle.

This works nearly flawlessly with a WebView that occupies its entire parent Activity. I am not sure how well it will work if there are multiple Views within your Activity at one time. It will likely require some tweaking in that case.

Comment: Need to update. Not working with compile SDK 26 and above.