# React Native | text highlighting

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react native app.
in one page of it I wan't to make a highlighting option like the following picture  [image]

but I can't customize the text popover to reach this behavior,

after many trials I reached the following result

[image]

Any idea how to add highlighting functionality?

Comment: I don't think there's an existing package for this. You will probably have to write an own native module using the WebView approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176395/how-to-override-web-view-text-selection-menu-in-android

Comment: @Peter Wilson any luck on identifying the package, I am also looking for a similar requirement in react native. Is something available now?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [react-native-highlight-words library](https://github.com/clauderic/react-native-highlight-words) . Might be it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just use a webview and use the injectedJavaScript prop