# How to override "Copy", "Share" and "Select All" options while selecting a text in a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-menu

I have a `TextView` where a user is able to select a text. By default the following options appear: "Copy", "Share" and "Select All".
I need to override them with custom options. But I can't find how to do that. I went through the documentation and [this nice article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999) but no lack. The article explains how to extend the menu when a user presses three-dots-button which is not what I need.

**Question:** How can I override default "Copy", "Share" and "Select All" options in text section menu?

Here is how my view looks like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/transcript"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

And in java code I have:

```
transcript.setTextIsSelectable(true);
transcript.setFocusable(true);
transcript.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `TextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()` to do this.

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(android.view.ActionMode.Callback)

I put together a very simple app to demonstrate how to use this feature.

**MainActivity.java**

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        CustomActionModeCallback callback = new CustomActionModeCallback(this);
        text.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(callback);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```html
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**CustomActionModeCallback.java**

```js
public class CustomActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

    private final Context context;

    public CustomActionModeCallback(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_custom, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.custom_one) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "One!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.custom_two) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Two!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.custom_three) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Three!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }
}
```

**menu_custom.xml**

```html
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/custom_one"
        android:title="One"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/custom_two"
        android:title="Two"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/custom_three"
        android:title="Three"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Nothing much to comment on in `MainActivity` or either xml file. All the magic happens in `CustomActionModeCallback`.

Both `onCreateActionMode()` and `onPrepareActionMode()` can be used to add your custom menu items to the menu. If you use `onCreateActionMode()`, the system will add some extra options into an overflow menu, like this:

[image]
[image]

If you use `onPrepareActionMode()`, the extra items won't be added.

[image]

Note that you must `return true` from `onCreateActionMode()` no matter what (returning false causes the menu to not be displayed), but you only have to `return true` from `onPrepareActionMode()` if you've actually modified the menu.

You can handle the user's clicks on your custom items inside `onActionItemClicked()`. In my example, I simply show a `Toast` and then close the contextual menu (using `ActionMode.finish()`). In this method, you should `return true` only on menu items that you handle yourself; returning false allows the system default action to happen (such as if you want to give the user the option to select all text).

Finally, `onDestroyActionMode()` is called when the menu is closed. Perhaps you have some use for this; I did not.

Comment: Thank you Ben! I didn't even expect such a detailed answer. You're doing great work for the community. Thanks again (I also voted up some other excellent  answers of yours).

Comment: is there a way to do this using css/javascript?

Comment: Great answer, very detailed.
Is there a way to show icons? I put it in the menu file, but they dont appear as icons, only the text.