# Webview, startActionMode() is not called

Tags: android, webview, cab

I need to have a customized text selection menu (CAB) in my Webview.
As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/use-a-custom-contextual-action-bar-for-webview-text-selection/22391169#22391169) is answered, I override startActionMode method, and it works fine

**THE PROBLEM:**

In some devices (two huawei devices as far as I tested) webview shows android default menu, and `startActionMode` method is not called at all.

I override other methods and the only method which gets called when I select some text is `showContextMenu()`.

I considered using a JS solution for this case, but I prefer to solve the issue simpler and with a native solution.

Moreover when I override `showContextMenu()` method, I noticed the stack trace is different in devices which work fine and the ones not.

**stack trace for devices work fine:**

```
    at com.rose.iknitoreader.views.ReaderWebView.showContextMenu(ReaderWebView.java:65)
    at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4279)
    at android.webkit.WebView.access$601(WebView.java:239)
    at android.webkit.WebView$PrivateAccess.super_performLongClick(WebView.java:1775)
    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.performLongClick(WebViewClassic.java:4455)
    at android.webkit.WebView.performLongClick(WebView.java:2105)
    at com.rose.iknitoreader.views.ReaderWebView.performLongClick(ReaderWebView.java:60)
    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.onHandleUiEvent(WebViewClassic.java:1354)
    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.access$7000(WebViewClassic.java:146)
    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$PrivateHandler.dispatchUiEvent(WebViewClassic.java:7655)
    at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchUiEvent(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:841)
    at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchUiEvents(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:829)
    at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.access$300(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:78)
    at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher$UiHandler.handleMessage(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:1118)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**stack trace for devices not working fine:**

```
    at com.rose.iknitoreader.views.ReaderWebView.showContextMenu(ReaderWebView.java:60)
    at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4496)
    at android.webkit.WebView.access$601(WebView.java:258)
    at android.webkit.WebView$PrivateAccess.super_performLongClick(WebView.java:1988)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.performLongClick(WebViewChromium.java:1690)
    at android.webkit.WebView.performLongClick(WebView.java:2365)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.offerGestureToEmbedder(ContentViewCore.java:3451)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.sendGesture(ContentViewCore.java:1426)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewGestureHandler.sendMotionEventAsGesture(ContentViewGestureHandler.java:1078)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewGestureHandler.access$1500(ContentViewGestureHandler.java:29)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewGestureHandler$1.onLongPress(ContentViewGestureHandler.java:582)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewGestureHandler.onLongPress(ContentViewGestureHandler.java:625)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.LongPressDetector.dispatchLongPress(LongPressDetector.java:157)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.LongPressDetector.access$000(LongPressDetector.java:21)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.LongPressDetector$LongPressHandler.handleMessage(LongPressDetector.java:58)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the issue I posted on Google issue tracker; https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79394037 the statue of this issue is wont fix
*Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)*